# SimpleOnGestureListener's onSingleTapUp never called

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I created a custom component with both an onTouchListener and a gesture detector,
I put the custom component in MainActivity's xml file which also has both onTouchEvent and a gesture detector.
I want to detect single taps on the custom component and long presses on MainActivity, but it seems somehow the touch listeners interact and the single taps never get detected.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private GestureDetector detector;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    detector = new GestureDetector(this, new LongPressDetector());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    switch (action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            Log.d("TouchEvent", "Action_Down at MainActivity.java");
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private class LongPressDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("TouchEvent", "onDown at MainActivity.java");
        return super.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("TouchEvent", "onLongPress at MainActivity.java");
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }
}
}
```

CustomView.java:

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {
private GestureDetector detector;

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context c){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customview, this);
    detector = new GestureDetector(c, new TapDetector());
    this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            int action = event.getActionMasked();
            switch (action){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                    Log.d("TouchEvent", "Action_Down at CustomView.java");
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private class TapDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("TouchEvent", "onDown at CustomView.java");
        return super.onDown(e);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("TouchEvent", "onSingleTapUp at CustomView.java");
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: add Log.d in your onTouch method and see the events

Comment: I did, if I tap on the custom component, the events fired in order are:
onDown at CustomView.java;
Action_Down at CustomView.java;
onDown at MainActivity.java;
Action_Down at MainActivity.java;
but no onSingleTapUp

Comment: and now read the docs on what omTouch returns

Comment: also if you are extending a View (RelativeLayout in your case) then override onTouchEvent instead of adding the listener (setOnTouchListener)

Comment: onSingleTapUp is fired if onTouch returns true, I didn't think it had any effect on the GestureDetector.

Comment: because if you return false for action_down you no longer receive any other events

Answer (score 20):

If you are going to respond to a tap up you also need to return true from onDown, the default will return false (I'm guessing here).

At least for me anyway, I wasn't getting `onSingleTapUp` called for my code until I made sure `onDown` returned true.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
```

I've seen other frameworks where 'up' events are only delivered if 'down' events are accepted, so I assumed that was what was happening here.

Answer (score 3):

**there is no need for guessing (@alexndr) !!!** look at sources

if u extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener call to super.onDown(event)

```
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
```

will return false but if u implement gesture detector listener then  there is no super !

```
public class GestureDetector {
/**
 * The listener that is used to notify when gestures occur.
 * If you want to listen for all the different gestures then implement
 * this interface. If you only want to listen for a subset it might
 * be easier to extend {@link SimpleOnGestureListener}.
 */
public interface OnGestureListener {

    /**
     * Notified when a tap occurs with the down {@link MotionEvent}
     * that triggered it. This will be triggered immediately for
     * every down event. All other events should be preceded by this.
     *
     * @param e The down motion event.
     */
    boolean onDown(MotionEvent e);
```

ps. rule is simple:

> **if EVENT is CONSUMED RETURN TRUE**
>   **if NOT RETURN FALSE**

Answer (score 1):

You just need return true in your `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`.

Somewhat like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    switch (action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            Log.d("TouchEvent", "Action_Down at MainActivity.java");
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up return true in onSingleTapUp as shown below for event

public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) { return true; }